# What does chmod -N do?

Tags: chmod, macos

In the [DropBox reinstall instructions](https://help.dropbox.com/installs-integrations/desktop/advanced-reinstall) for Mac there was the line `sudo chmod -N ~`. I looked for the `-N` option but I didn't find anything about it.

Could someone explain what this option means precisely in this case?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

From the macOS `chmod(1)` manual (`man chmod`):

> ACL MANIPULATION OPTIONS
>
> [...]
>
> `-N`      Removes the ACL from the named file(s).

That is, `chmod -N ~` would clear the access control list (ACL) from the home directory.

Comment: Thank you very much! Is there a command I can use to revert to the previous permissions? Or I should use for instance the instructions [here](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT203538) to and use `repairHomePermissions`. I'm not sure I want an empty ACL for my home directory.

Comment: @NikolayD I'm sorry, but I can not answer that with any sort of authority. Reinstalling macOS as the last step in that chain of actions suggests, seems a bit strange, but appears to be official Apple recommendations. I will not say yay nor nay.